# How to save raster results of IExtractionOp?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I'm using IExtractionOp to clip a raster by polygon:

```
IExtractionOp operation = (IExtractionOp)(new RasterExtractionOp());
IRasterBandCollection rasterBandCollection = (IRasterBandCollection)operation.Polygon((IGeoDataset)rasterDataset, polygon, true);
```

I tried saving via

```
// Fails with exception
IRasterDataset dataset = rasterBandCollection.Item(0).RasterDataset;
dataset.Copy("temp" + extension, (IWorkspace)rasterWorkspace);

// Successful, but does not show any pixels in ArcMap when opened
rasterBandCollection.SaveAs("temp" + extension, (IWorkspace)rasterWorkspace, rasterDataset.Format);

// Same result as SaveAs
((ITemporaryDataset)dataset).MakePermanentAs("temp" + extension, (IWorkspace)rasterWorkspace, rasterDataset.Format);
```

None of the three methods above worked... I can use the returned result and add it to the map, so the extraction seems to be valid, but I'm unable to store it anyhow.

Comment: Did you try setting [IRasterAnalysisEnvironment.OutputWorkspace](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00240000001r000000) on the RasterExtractionOp?

Comment: Thank you - you gave me the successful hint: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Data_processing_in_spatial_analysis_operations/0001000003sn000000/ - I will post an answer later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ArcGIS 10 there a two documentated possibilities:

Using ITemporaryDataset.MakePermanentAs as documentated [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Performing_a_spatial_analysis_operation_using_objects/00010000048n000000/).

This however leads to the result described above - a very small (unuseable) file is generated. I noticed that sometimes the file changes to a usable file after the debug process is closed (respectively ArcMap). I found out that explicitly freeing the result of MakePermanentAs leads to the same result, which is an acceptable workaround for me.

```
IDataset raster = temporaryDataset.MakePermanentAs(filename, (IWorkspace)rasterWorkspace, format);

// Free result explicitly (workaround)
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(raster);
```

Second possibility is to use IRasterOPBase as described [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Data_processing_in_spatial_analysis_operations/0001000003sn000000/):

```
// Creates RasterDatasetName object as output dataset name
IDatasetName datasetName = (IDatasetName)new RasterDatasetName();
datasetName.WorkspaceName = (IWorkspaceName)((IDataset)rasterWorkspace).FullName;
datasetName.Name = filename;

// Adds output dataset name to Op (force 10 execution path)
IRasterOpBase rasterOpBase = (IRasterOpBase)operation;
rasterOpBase.AddOutputDatasetName(0, datasetName);
```

This however randomly fails when using it in a STA Thread - so I have to stick with solution number one.